# How to install a msi using python script?

Tags: python, windows, installation

Is there any python script to install a msi? I need to install msi and run it without showing any dialogue modal.
I have msi on my folder c:\user\documents and i have a wxpython GUI developed using python script.I need to silent install msi and run the exe from the GUI.

Comment: I think this one would be better suited on SO.

Answer (score 9):

simple use. No transforms provided, and code is non-blocking:

```
import os
os.system('msiexec /i %s /qn' % msi_location)
```

With transforms, and code is non-blocking:

```
import os
os.system('msiexec /i %s TRANSFORMS=%s /qn' % (msi_location, transforms_location)
```

With transforms, and code is blocking - so you know when it has completed:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('msiexec /i %s TRANSFORMS=%s /qn' % (msi_location, transforms_location), shell=True)
```

For more info on TRANSFORMS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367447%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a python question, and it depends if your specific MSI package allow unattended installation. See this SO article

[detect msi parameters for unattended install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366480/detect-msi-parameters-for-unattended-install)

how to find out about the parameters of an MSI package. Then, try the unattended installation manually using the windows command shell, calling `msiexec`. See here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

for more information.

Finally, all you need to do in python is to use `os.system` to call `msiexec` with the name of the package and the correct parameters.