# Run a required .msi installer from setup.py so it runs with pip install

Tags: python, windows, installation, windows-installer, pypi

I have coded [this small python library](https://github.com/yannbouteiller/vgamepad) that I distribute on PyPI (vgamepad), and that needs [ViGEmBus](https://github.com/ViGEm/ViGEmBus) installed to work.

ViGEmBus is a Windows driver, it is installed by double-clicking a .msi file, granting admin privileges, and waiting for the end of installation. This .msi file is present in my library.

My question is: is there a way to modify setup.py so that, when running

```sh
pip install vgamepad
```

the .msi file runs as well (with Windows asking asking the user for permission to install the driver) and the user doesn't have to install it manually for the library to work? I suppose some big frameworks do this kind of things so hopefully it is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better question to ask might be this => [How to install a msi using python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519958/how-to-install-a-msi-using-python-script/14522827)

FYI: that question already has a valid answer

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into this. Is this doable directly within the setup.py script and compatible with pip install?