# List Tables in an msi file?

Tags: sql, windows-installer

How does one use [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366480/detect-msi-parameters-for-unattended-install) to list the [tables in an MSI file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/examples-of-database-queries-using-sql-and-script)?

Comment: I updated the script to support drag-and-drop of MSI files onto the VBScript. Should make it faster to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***MSI SDK***: The [_Tables table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/-tables-table) is a read-only system table that lists all the
> tables in the database. Query this table to find out if a table
> exists.

Adapting the script **`WiExport.vbs`** from the [Windows Installer Scripting Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-scripting-examples) from the [Windows Installer SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-portal) you get something like the below.

---

> ***MSI SDK VBScripts***: In order to find **`WiExport.vbs`**: With Visual Studio installed, look under:  **`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86`** (adjust
> version numbers for your current installation) (or just search for it on github.com).

---

***Sample Screen Shot***: Here is a sample run of the script below:

[image]

***Sample***: Procedure for script:

- **`1)`** save as [**`ListMSITables.vbs`**](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/ListMSITables.vbs) on desktop (link to github.com)
- **`2)`** drag-and-drop an MSI file onto the VBScript
- **`3)`** a message box will show number of tables, and table names

***Note***: Very large MSI files could make the message box overflow the screen. Just press any key to dismiss (I use **`ESC`**).

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Const msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly = 0

Dim installer : Set installer = Nothing
Set installer = Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Dim counter : counter = 0

' Verify incoming drag and drop arguments
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then MsgBox "Drag and drop an MSI file onto the VBScript" End If
filename = Wscript.Arguments(0)
If (Right (LCase(filename),3) <> "msi") Then 
   WScript.Quit
End If

Dim database : Set database = installer.OpenDatabase(filename, msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly)
Dim table, view, record

Set view = database.OpenView("SELECT `Name` FROM _Tables")
view.Execute

Do
    Set record = view.Fetch
    If record Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    table = record.StringData(1)
    tables = tables + table + vbNewLine
    counter = counter + 1
Loop

MsgBox "Number of tables: " + CStr(counter) + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + tables

Set view = Nothing
```

> [***Github.com***](https://github.com/): The above is obviously VBScript. Just [pillage github.com](https://github.com/search?q=_Tables%20msi&type=Code) for more
> of the same, in all kinds of languages.

---

***Links:***

- [Post-Process MSI using MSI SDK VBScript WiRunSQL.vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51103086/129130)